# textbox in c# (wp7) in 1 line

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have problem with 2 Textblocks in my WP7 project (in expression blend).

I put them [text block][text block] in a grid, and the problem is that text of 1st text block is random, once got 5 char, once 10 char, and first text block is on second text block.

example:

```
[First Text][Second Text]
[First Text Dadada] Text]
```

I would like to make them:

```
[First Text][Second Text]
[First Text Dadadda][Second Text]
```

Answer (score 2):

Put each textbox in its own column of the grid (`Grid.Column="..."` attribute to specify that) *or* wrap them into a `StackPanel` specifying `Orientation=Horizontal`

Answer (score 0):

Your grid should be automatically resizable and both textBlocks should be assigned their respective columns.

Example, consider the following grid layout for your problem:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now, assign columns to your textBlocks (declared inside the grid), e.g:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

That should do it.